# HighCharts Polar Labels in between of sectors of circle

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I am working ReactHigh charts on polar graphs, I want my labels to come in between the sectors of the circle, they are coming on points but i dont want them to come there.

JSfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ra73mp0c/12/

Also I want a background color on each of the labels.
Graph as of now :
[image]

Desried Outcome :

[image]

Please help me .

Config of graph :

```
    const config = {
      chart: {
       polar: true,
       type: 'line',
        width: 700,
       backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      plotBorderWidth: null,
       margin: [0, 0, 0, 0],
      spacingTop: 0,
       spacingBottom: 0,
        spacingLeft: 0,
      spacingRight: 0

  },

  title: {
    text: null
  },

  pane: {
    size: '80%'
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: [
      'Sales',
      'Sales',
      'Sales',
      'Sales',
      'Marketing',
      'Development',
      'Customer Support',
      'Customer Support',
      'Customer Support',
      'Information Technology'
    ],
    labels: {
      style: {
        fontSize: '13px',
        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
      }
    },
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on'
  },

  yAxis: {
    gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
    min: 0,
    tickInterval: 1,
    max: 6
  },

  tooltip: {
    shared: true
  },

  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  credits: { enabled: false },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Allocated Budget',
      data: [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4, 1],
      pointPlacement: 'between'
    },
    {
      name: 'Actual Spending',
      data: [2, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 4],
      pointPlacement: 'between'
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks a lot, It would be helpful ig you can edit the fiddle Link https://jsfiddle.net/ra73mp0c/12/

Comment: Just want to question your desired outcome. Does it really make sense? For example, you have a value right between `Purpose` and `People`. How should the reader know to which value it is referencing to? Wouldn't it be better to have the chart just like you have now but with the point on the line like here: https://jsfiddle.net/oou04tab/ ?

Comment: @JoãoMenighin okay agreed how to make that background color, can you please help

Answer (score 1):

Creating that kind of background for x axis labels is not supported in Highcharts.

As a **workaround** you can create a phantom series that mimics their look:

```
{
  showInLegend: false,
  type: 'polygon',
  name: 'Labels background',
  data: [
    [1, 5],
    [2, 5],
    [2, 6],
    [1, 6]
  ],
  zIndex: -9999
}
```

`labels.distance` should be a negative value to make it work.

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/63nc1csv/